# what is difference between Node * next and Node<T> * next?

Tags: c++, injected-class-name

I was writing implementation of Linked List

in the bellow code we have `Node<T> * next;` and `Node * next;`
I think both are doing same as pointing to object of Node class or there is difference between them.

```
template<typename T>
class Node{
    T data;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node * next;
    Node()
    {
        next = nullptr;
    }
    Node(T val)
    {
        this->data = val;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: See [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

Comment: If next does not use T for a definition or a calculation, why even use Node<T> ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between `Node<T> * next;` and `Node * next;`, if both are declared inside the class body.

As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

> In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a
> template-name of the class template itself:
>
> - it is followed by <
> - it is used as a template argument that    corresponds to a template    template parameter
> - it is the final    identifier in the elaborated class specifier of a    friend class    template declaration.
>
> Otherwise, it is treated as a type-name, and is equivalent to the
> template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
> template enclosed in <>.

So the name `Node * next` is resolved into `Node<T>* next;`.

Comment: and what if it is outside the class.